# Difference of running an application from within and outside MSVS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, xna, xna-4.0

I noticed that an application that I am developing (a game written in C# / XNA) occasionally behaves differently depending on whether it is started from within Microsoft Visual Studio (2010) compared to when it is started outside MSVS (e.g. from Windows Explorer). Specifically, sometimes I get errors (exceptions are drawn) that do not occur within MSVS.

What could be the reason for this difference? Ideally there would be a way to make MSVS check the application as strictly as possible such that I can be sure that all bugs really occur (and can be fixed) during development.

The problem happens in both release and debug mode. The game uses a number of external dlls (nuclex lib, sharp dx) but these libs are all used both from within MSVS and outside. The game entirely runs in a single thread.

**Please note that the question is not about a specific error that I need to debug, but it is about general differences that (could) arise from the way an application is started.**

Comment: Debug informations are needed here...

Comment: @zarathos: Sorry if this was not well formulated, but my problem is not a specific error but it is about general differences that (could) arise from the way an application is started

Comment: Well i can't be sure about this but i've had sort of similar things happen on one of my programs. It took a lot of poking around and separating to find out what the faulty driver was. And that is my advice to sneaky bugs like this. Try your best to separate and test independently all your code. How to narrow it down? well you might also try looking into your Windows Error events.

Comment: OK so, just make examples. Is your game using binary resources from another location? Are you getting exceptions? Are you running it after being compiled as Debug or Release? Are you using different settings? Normally there should be no differences!

Comment: I also want to point out that having a debugger running in a virtual host at the same can "slow" things down enough to have a race event (or to fix a race event). That same program at one time would not run at all from VS... That got old!

Comment: @RobertSnyder - excellent point. I've seen the same behavior, i.e. a race condition which was hidden by the performance hit caused by having a debugger attached. Unit/stress tests will mostly eliminate this problem.

Comment: @Robert : Thank you for your hints but I have no problem fixing eventual bugs that occur, I was just wondering what could be different in the way the application is running.

Comment: @pad_ares - we *are* pointing out a difference; the debugger often slows the application down, and that can lead to subtle differences in how the application behaves.

Comment: @tim: Even if the application runs in a single thread?

Comment: I can aswer that... Yes, even in [STA] Events are seemingly run from a different thread. To verify try updating a label from an event :)

Comment: To make this discussion productive, I'd suggest picking a single, reproducible error and updating the question with as much info as possible. Otherwise, we can only discuss generalities, which might be irrelevant to the actual problem. I know you are *looking* for general ideas, but the possibilities are almost endless without more detail.

Comment: I don't know much about that, but from my own experience, if your game often uses exceptions (`try, catch`) this may heavily reduce the framerate while inside VS, so if you have anything that relies on timers, it may be affected by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main things that cause your program to run differently, when run in Visual Studio.

First of all, the [Visual Studio hosting process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331.aspx). I think it's disabled by default. But the toggle for it, if you need it, is in the "Debug" tab of the properties for your application project.

The second, is the fact that the .NET JIT will emit different, more debuggable machine code when a debugger is attached. You can disable [this behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241594(v=vs.100).aspx) by unchecking the "**Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed only)**" checkbox in  Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General.

You could try disabling this option and then running your game under the debugger and seeing if the same error occurs. Note, of course, that disabling this will make your program *significantly* harder to debug - but it does help in a case like this one.

As was mentioned in comments, it is almost unheard of for this kind of problem to be related to the code-generation (although, theoretically, I suppose it's possible). Latent threading bugs caused by changes in performance are far more likely. It could also be a badly behaved native library - although this is also unusual.